# How to download all reactions of the TCA cycle from the RHEA database with the SPARQL endpoint?

Tags: api

I am looking for a way to use the [SPARQL endpoint of RHEA](https://sparql.rhea-db.org/sparql) to download all reactions of the [TCA cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle) in CSV or JSON format.